# Error loading spring camel context (type mismatch)

Tags: java, spring, apache-camel, apache-servicemix

I'm using Fuse IDE (Eclipse) on a little project with a spring camel context, one route, and one test. I put an extra xml for defining test execution environment.

When I run the test, it fails with type mismatch loading the context bean info (when instantiating PropertyDescriptor class of the bean context, setter type is org.apache.camel.spring.SpringCamelContext and getter type is org.apache.camel.model.ModelCamelContext...

The original exception is: "java.beans.IntrospectionException: type mismatch between read and write methods"

The test code is this:

```
public class TestDBRoute extends CamelSpringTestSupport {   

@DirtiesContext //reload context
@Test
public void testPoll() throws Exception {
    //context.start();
    System.out.println("comenzo");
    Thread.sleep(1000);
    System.out.println("termino");
    //context.stop();
    assertEquals("first", 1, 1);
}

@Override
protected AbstractApplicationContext createApplicationContext() {
    return new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("classpath:/com/test-camel-context.xml");
}
}
```

The camel context code is:

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
   xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
   xsi:schemaLocation="
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
   http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring/camel-spring.xsd">

<camelContext xmlns="http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring">
        <packageScan>
            <package>com.test.fuse.routes</package>
        </packageScan>
</camelContext>
</beans>
```

The route code is empty, it only extends the RouteBuilder and overrides the configure method.

I'm using OpenJDK 1.6.0_24 on ubuntu.

If you need something else please ask.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I just clean the workspace and changed my spring version from 2.5.4 to 2.5.6 on the pom.xml and everything works.

Thanks to Claud Ibsen and Babak Vahdat for their help.